# How to delete first n characters from each first line of multiple files using bash?

Tags: bash, sed

I have big number of exports. All files have same structure. I need to remove first 15 characters from each first line in each file in the same directory.

I tried this piece but this removed first 15 characters from every line:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.json
do
    sed 's/^.\{15\}//' "$file" > "$file".new
    mv "$file".new "$file"
done
```

The line looks like this:

```
  "dashboard": {
```

and I want the line to start with { .

Comment: Cases there are not the same. Replacement and deletion are not the same terms. I've edited my original comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in ./*.json; do
   sed -i '1s/.*/{/' "$file"
done
```

**explanation**

```
# loop over all *.json files in current directory 
for file in ./*.json; do

   # -i use inplace replacement
   # replace first line with '{'
   sed -i '1s/.*/{/' "$file"
done
```

Comment: or only `sed -i '1s/.*/{/' *.json`.

Comment: Maybe `sed  -i  '1c{' *.json`.